# ld: library not found for -lnetcdf

Tags: cmake, gfortran, netcdf

I am new to CMake. I can not resolve the flowing error. Could someone help me?

------------ERROR--------------

```
ld: library not found for -lnetcdf
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [NUP] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/NUP.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/NUP.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [NUP] Error 2
```

------------------- CMake File------------------

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(NUP Fortran)
enable_language(Fortran)

set(INCLUDE_FILE /usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4/include)
set(lib_FILE /usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4/lib)
find_package(netcdf  REQUIRED)
if(netcdf_FOUND)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_FILE})

set(
        SOURCE_FILES
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} unpack.f90
)

add_executable(NUP ${SOURCE_FILES} )
target_link_libraries(NUP netcdf)
endif()
```

--------------unpack.f90-------------------

```
PROGRAM unpack_array

  IMPLICIT NONE
  INCLUDE 'netcdf.inc'

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307)
......
```

---

I am using MACOS Catalina. Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `find_package()` to find NetCDF on your machine, you shouldn't need to manually specify the paths as you have. Let `find_package` do that for you.

Note: CMake doesn't ship with a [Find Module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#id4) for NetCDF, so you'll have to download one (like [this one](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/master/CMake/FindNetCDF.cmake)) from the internet. Then, you need to tell CMake where to locate this `FindNetCDF.cmake` file on your system using `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Finally, you can use the `NetCDF::NetCDF` *imported* target to link NetCDF to your project's targets.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)
project(NUP Fortran)
# Don't need this, you already enabled Fortran above in the 'project' call.
enable_language(Fortran)

set(INCLUDE_FILE /usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4/include)
set(lib_FILE /usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4/lib)

# Add the location of the 'FindNetCDF.cmake' file to your module path.
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/path/to/downloaded/find/module")
# Then, call find package for NetCDF. 
find_package(NetCDF REQUIRED)

if(${NetCDF_FOUND})
    # Don't need this if you use the imported target below.
    include_directories(${INCLUDE_FILE})

    # Don't provide directories with source file list.
    set(SOURCE_FILES
        ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} 
        unpack.f90
    )

    add_executable(NUP ${SOURCE_FILES})

    # Use the imported target to link netcdf instead.
    target_link_libraries(NUP PRIVATE NetCDF::NetCDF)
endif()
```

As commented, there are other approaches to adding NetCDF to your CMake project. If you use a **different** find module, the syntax of the provided NetCDF CMake variables and imported targets may be slightly different. You'll have to examine the find module file itself.

In addition, you may instead use a CMake **package configuration file** (e.g. `netCDFConfig.cmake`) downloaded from the internet to add NetCDF to your project. In this case, you would still use `find_package()`, but you would specify the configuration file's location using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, rather than `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

You can find **detailed** descriptions for each of these approaches in the CMake [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/find_package.html#command:find_package) documentation. I highly encourage you spend some time to read it.

Comment: Since the code in the question has no `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` setting, it is more likely that asker uses "Config" file for find the package, not the "Find" file. [That config file](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-c/blob/master/netCDFConfig.cmake.in) declares `netCDF::netcdf` as an IMPORTED target.

Comment: I am appreciated for your help! Tanks both of you. I modified my code just with your advice.  But I get another ERROR, which I can't solve:                                 
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_nf_close_", referenced from: _MAIN__ in unpack.f90.o

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I see now that CMake doesn't provide a Find Module out-of-the-box.

Comment: @mengjiewarmuth I just found some time to update my response. I provided more detail for adding NetCDF to your project. Hope this helps!